# Implementing a limited attempt system in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{


    int rnd = 1 + (rand() % 99999);
    char comp;
    cout << "Introduzca el valor a comparar" << endl;

    cin >> comp;

    if (comp > rnd)
    {
        cout << ">";
    }
    else if (comp < rnd)
    {
        cout << "<";
    }
    else if (comp = rnd)
    {
        cout << "=";
    }
}
```

So, in this C++ program I'm trying to get the user to guess a number, but I want them to have a limited number of tries at guessing (20). I have basically zero experience in C++ and I don't know how to implement this system.

Comment: Have you considered using a [`for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) loop?

Comment: Think of how you would do this without a computer. You'd keep a count of the number of tries and kick the player ut when they've run out of tries. And while you at it, `else if (comp = rnd)` is an accidental assignment. You want `==`.

Comment: `int rnd = 1 + (rand() % 99999);` - 1) using a C generator with really poor properties. 2) using modulo in a way that biases the random numbers.

Comment: And using a modulo that [may exceed `RAND_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX)

Comment: PSA: `=` and `==` are **vastly different**. When learning you must learn to spot mistakes like this. I immediately noticed it, but it's only because I look specifically for things like this.

Comment: Tip: If you've excluded all other possibilities, use a default `else` at the end. This avoids mistakes. Your code only "works" by sheer chance. If you reorder the `if` statements it breaks.

Comment: Hint: `while (guesses < max_guesses)`

Comment: Sorry for all of the beginner mistakes, kinda threw myself at the problem without checking tutorials.

Comment: Not only is `comp = rnd` an accidental assignment, it's wholly unnecessary. You've already eliminated the possibilities `comp > rnd` and `comp < rnd`. What other state could exist aside from `comp == rnd`?

Comment: And no one's mentioned yet that you won't get a different random number when you re-run the program. Your sequence is deterministic.

Comment: Be cautious with tutorials. Until you have enough familiarity with the language to detect frauds and madmen, you have to do extra research to establish the credibility of the tutorial's writer. Sucks to invest a bunch of time into writing code based on the rantings of a lunatic or some overconfident know-nothing trying to generate ad revenue. The best way to gain familiarity is through a well-curated resource like a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4581301).